# Definir constante em Python

Tags: python, constantes

Como posso declarar uma constante em Python da mesma forma que faço em C com

```c
#Define PI 3.1415
```

ou em java

```java
public final double PI = 3.1415
```

Comment: No caso se criar uma tupla?
pi = (3.141592)

Comment: Este é o campo exclusivo para respostas. Se tem uma pergunta que foi não foi respondida, pode utilizar o botão "Faça uma pergunta". Aliás, o trecho que colocou não define uma tupla, pois, neste caso, os parenteses serão utilizados apenas para gerenciamento de precedência de operadores na expressão. Para criar uma tupla precisaria fazer `pi = (3.141592,)`, com a vírgula, mas isso não seria semântico.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Em Python (em versões menores que a 3.8) isso não é possível. Apenas crie uma variável e não mude o seu valor.

```
PI = 3.1415
```

---

Essa segunda opção não teria o mesmo efeito de uma constante, uma vez que é possível reescrever uma função em outras partes do código.

<strike>Um *workaround* simples, se realmente for **muito necessário** ter total garantia de que este valor nunca vai ser reescrito em outra parte do código é criar uma função que retorne o valor desejado.</strike>

```
def const_pi():
    return 3.1415
```

Comment: Exceto se alguém reescrever a função `const_pi` em outra parte do código haha

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Verdade. Eu acho que tava na cabeça que não era possível redefinir funções.

Comment: LINQ, já que editou, não seria interessante remover a sugestão de definir uma função visto que ela não garante que seja constante como diz na resposta?

Answer (score 12):

Não tem. Não se esqueça que Python é uma linguagem de *script*, por isso ela não precisa suprir todos mecanismos que outras linguagens possuem.

O jeito é fazer:

```
alguma_coia = 10 #não mexa neste valor, ele deve ser constante
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Constant.py).

Answer (score 11):

Na versão 3.8 do Python foi adicionado no módulo [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) o tipo `Final` justamente para representar que um nome não poderá sofrer reatribuição, mas assim como toda a anotação de tipos do Python, isso não garante em tempo de execução, apenas informa ferramentas externas de validação de tipos.

```py
from typing import Final

PI: Final = 3.14159
PI = 4

print(PI)
```

Ao executar o código acima você terá como saída o valor `4`, pois mesmo indicado que o nome `PI` é um valor final não alterará o comportamento em tempo de execução. Porém, ao executar o `mypy` nesse mesmo arquivo você obteria um erro indicando que há uma reatribuição em um valor final.

```
(.env) ➜  mypy main.py 
main.py:4: error: Cannot assign to final name "PI"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Você pode inclusive utilizá-lo em conjunto com outro tipo para especificar o tipo real da variável:

```
PI: Final[float] = 3.14
```

Answer (score 10):

Como colocado nas outras respostas, Python, sendo uma linguagem dinâmica,
não tem o recurso de "constantes" de uma forma simples: tudo em Python é um objeto. 
Quando você define um número literal em código Python, na verdade, esse número é uma constante - o compilador que gera o bytecode coloca o valor literal dele no .pyc  -só que, pela natureza da linguagem, qualquer variável é apenas um nome vinculado a um objeto -e  a qualquer momento,
você pode simplesmente vincular o nome a um outro objeto.

No uso normal, assume-se que "Python é uma linguagem feita para ser usada por adultos que consentem com o que estão fazendo" - então um valor declarado no corpo de um módulo, apontado por um nome com letras maiúsculas, é, por convenção, tratado como uma constante, e não se deve mudar o valor daquela variável. Simples assim.

Entenda  se você tem essas duas linhas em seu código, o valor 3.141592 continua existindo na memória. Só que a variável Pi agora vai fazer referência a um objeto float em outra posição da memória:

```
Pi = 3.141592
Pi = Pi + 1
```

Agora, Python permite uma personalização quase sem limites da forma como dados são acessados se eles são atributos de uma classe (se são variáveis de um módulo, a história é outra, mas hacks são possíveis).

Descrever esses mecanismos e sugerir varias formas de criar coisas parecidas com constantes seria possível, mas avançado demais, e teria o tamanho de um capítulo de livro.

Em vez disso, vamos nos ater a um exemplo: a classe da biblitoeca padrão "Enum" pode ser usada para criar classes com "constantes" dentro - que além de um valor que não pode ser alterado de forma direta, ainda tem outras propriedades como "nome legível", dentre outras:

```
import enum

class Numeros(enum.Enum):
    pi = 3.141592

print (Numeros.pi, Numeros.pi.value)
```

exibe:

```
(<Numeros.pi: 3.141592>, 3.141592)
```

E tentar fazer:

```
Numeros.pi = 4
```

resulta em:

```
AttributeError: Cannot reassign members.
```

Esse mecanismo de Enum usa o dinamismo de Python para fazer uma coisa que não é possível fazer nas linguagens que tem as constantes "normais" que você menciona: em tempo de execução é possível usar o nome da constante. Isso é: em C é impossível você imprimir "PI" se usar um `#define PI 3.141592` - uma vez que o define é um search and replace. Algumas bibliotecas tem suporte a usar o Enum  de C de forma  a poder olhar o nome  em tempo de execução (acredito) - mas em Python, basta fazer:

```
print(Numeros.pi.name)
```

Para ver o texto "pi" impresso.E se desejar usar o valor de forma numérica, deve-se usar o atributo "value": `print(Numeros.pi.value)`