# Como inicializar uma constante com o valor de time.Now() em Golang?

Tags: variáveis, golang, constantes

Estou acostumado a fazer projetos em Python onde, ao inicializar o mesmo eu guardo uma variável dizendo quando ele iniciou (para poder medir o tempo de execução do projeto) assim:

```py
import time
started_at = time.perf_counter()
```

Assim no final do código eu posso calcular a diferença entre o `started_at` e um novo `time.perf_counter()` e saber o tempo de execução do código.

Estou começando a estudar Golang agora e, ao tentar fazer a mesma coisa está aparecendo uma mensagem de erro "const initializer &time.Now() is not a constant" . Segue o código que comecei a montar:

```
package app

import "time"

const startedAt = time.Now()
```

O que preciso fazer para poder ter o mesmo comportamento do primeiro código em Golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ter o mesmo comportamento você deve usar `var` e não `const`:

```
package app

import "time"

var startedAt = time.Now()
```

*Quando a variável está dentro de uma função também é possível usar o `:=` para criar a variável (como `startedAt := time.Now()`).*

---

O Golang não permite utilizar funções como constante. Isto serve para tudo, mesmo aquilo que, em tese, é constante. Da mesma maneira que não pode usar `const v = time.Now()`, você não pode usar `const v = math.Abs(1.2)`.

---

Toda regra tem exceções, existem poucas funções que podem ser usadas como `const`, a maioria delas é pertencente ao `unsafe`,  que o próprio nome já dá uma pista do que se trata. Além de algumas funções (e em alguns casos) que já são da própria linguagem (com o `len`).

Se for [ver a documentação do `unfsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), pode notar o comentário:

> // The return value of Alignof is a Go constant.

Então, é possível utilizar um `const c = unsafe.Sizeof([]int{})`. Também pode utilizar `const c = len("abc")`, mas não pode usar `len([]int{1,2,3})`, já que slice não são constantes.

Comment: Simples, direto e exatamente o que eu precisava saber do "porque" não funcionar. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

> fazer projetos em Python onde, ao inicializar o mesmo eu guardo uma **variável**

Destaquei a palavra variável. Não consigo imaginar porque tentou usar uma constante em Go se em Python usou uma variável, se quer fazer o mesmo então escreva um código compatível, não introduza uma outra semântica.

Uma constante deve ser um valor que não mudará nunca. Um horário é a definição perfeita de algo que muda, é impossível pegar o mesmo dado em duas execuções.

Parece acreditar que constante é uma variável que não muda seu valor e isso não é correto. Para entender melhor: [Constante é realmente útil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203151/101) (siga os *links*).

> O que preciso fazer para poder ter o mesmo comportamento do primeiro código em Golang?

Manter o dado como uma variável. Só trocar `const` por `var` ou atribuir com `:=`.

Se quer uma variável imutável, Go, [hoje](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27975), não tem isso, assim como [Python não tem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195351/101) nem mesmo constante.

Eu não acho que só isso fará o comportamento do código em Python acontecer em Go, afinal em Python está usando um biblioteca de análise de performance e em Go está usando uma biblioteca que trabalha com horário normal. Eu sei que é intuitivo a pessoa achar que é só pegar o horário que começou e que terminou a operação, subtrair um do outro e sabe quanto tempo demorou, mas essas bibliotecas de horário não costumam ter resolução e precisão suficiente para entregar resultados confiáveis para análise de desempenho.

Até onde eu sei se faz isso com [`go test`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/), então pra que reinventar a roda?

[image: Caminhonete com rodas quadradas]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Por você querer contar o tempo, achei trabalhoso sua maneira, para meus projetos uso esse método:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var end chan bool
var tsecs chan string

func init() {
    end = make(chan bool)
    tsecs = make(chan string)
}

func main() {
    go contador()

    //exemplo de código executando!
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

    //encerrar
    end <- true
    res := <-tsecs
    fmt.Printf("%s seconds", res)
}

func contador() {
    var seconds int = 0
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        seconds++
        select {
        case <-end:
            tsecs <- fmt.Sprintf("%d", seconds)
            break
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Encarrego da GOROUTINE contabilizar, no meu caso estou contando os segundos, mas é possível alterar para unidades menores modificando o time.Sleep()